# Secure Hadoop - Start Datanode in background

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, kerberos, sasl, datanode

I'm running hadoop 3.1.2 and I'm setting authentication on my cluster. For performance reasons, I do not want data encryption on my setup, only authentication. I've read that part about securing datanodes :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Secure+DataNode

As I don't want encryption, I went with the privileged resources method (from what I've understood, SASL encrypts communications and thus have an impact on performances). The problem is that I need to start datanodes as the root user individually. Using start-dfs.sh does not start datanodes since it starts with my hadoop user. When I use the hdfs datanode command, I can't do anything else on my server with that session.

Is there any way to start datanodes in the background ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out that I can just run

> hdfs datanode &

for the datanode to run in background. I also tried to run start-dfs.sh with sudo on my master node but it eventually failed to start datanodes (root doesn't have any keys for ssh). I will go back to using SASL since it looks way simpler to implement and run.